# How to add a leftJoin to a Symfony 1.4 form filter

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms, doctrine-1.2

So I'm need to add a filter to an admin screen in a legacy application. Basically some customers have a billing auto topup enabled, and the admins want to be able to filter by those customers in the admin screen.

I think the way to do this is by adding and appropriate filter which I've done, however the query isn't being modified correctly. The filter code looks like:

```
public function addAutoTopupColumnQuery(Doctrine_Query $query, $field, $value)
    {
        $value = intval($value);

        switch ($value) {

            default: 
            case(0): {
            //Any is set - nothing to do.
                break;
            }

            case(1): {
                //Enabled is set - left join the table
                $query->leftJoin($query->getRootAlias() . '.BillingAutoTopup billingAutoTopup');
                break;
            }

            case(2): {
                //Without is set - todo implement
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Using that gives an error as it appears the query is trying to join the `BillingAutoTopup` table to the previous table in the query, rather than the correct table, which is the first one in the query.

How do I either order the filter so that it is run as the first item, or how do I change the doctrine query to join a table to a specific table that is already in the query?

Oh and yes it's doctrine 1 not 2.

Comment: Can you show us your `generator.yml`? If you want to retrieve the join alias, you should define your own query in the admin generator so you can set the relation name.